# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-like

I am working on a SQL Server stored procedure. I have table with these columns

```
BusName(NVarchar(100) not null)
BusNumber(int, null)
```

in my main `Bus` table.

I am trying to implement search functionality where user can either pass `BusName` or `BusNumber` to get all the results stored in main `Bus` table

I have implemented this stored procedure to handle the search functionality:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllBus]
    @BusName VARCHAR(512),
    @BusNo INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
BEGIN
     SELECT 
         [BusName], 
         [ManagingOwner],
         [Operator],
         [CurrentService], [CurrentRate],
         [BusNumber],
         [MarketRate],
         [EarliestRdel]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Bus] 
     WHERE 
         [BusName] LIKE '%' + @BusName + '%' 
         OR [BusNumber] LIKE '%' + @BusNo + '%' 
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spGetAllBus]
        @BusName = N'emma',
        @BusNo = NULL
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.

I am struggling to find the root cause as I am not having any conversions in the code. Can someone help me here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You **cannot** use `LIKE` on a numerical value...

Comment: yes you cannot pass the LIKE on INT values, As you mentioned Bus Number is INT,
you can use the equal operator to Bus Number instead of the Like, and bus number field should accept the NULL value as well then only you can pass the NULL to check

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the user passes both parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter your stored procedure like below if your BusNumber column's type is INT.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllBus]
   @BusName VARCHAR(512),
   @BusNo INT
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  
BEGIN
 SELECT 
     [BusName], 
     [ManagingOwner],
     [Operator],
     [CurrentService], [CurrentRate],
     [BusNumber],
     [MarketRate],
     [EarliestRdel]
 FROM 
     [dbo].[Bus] 
 WHERE 
     [BusName] LIKE '%' + @BusName + '%' 
     OR [BusNumber] = @BusNo 
END
```